# matlab coder report Size mismatch (size [0 x 0] ~= size [1 x 2])

Tags: matlab, mex, matlab-coder

I tried to use matlab coder to convert my matlab file into C\C++ source file. In my *.m file,I defined a dynamic array:

```
...
...
coord_list = [];
I_list = [];

...
for i=1:n
    ....
    coordinate = yy;
    I = zz;
    coord_list = [coord_list;coordinate];
    I_list = [I_list;I]
    
    %% handle with coord_list and I_list
    coord_list = f(coord_list);
    I_list = g(I_list);
    
    %% the iteration stopped if the condition is meet
    if condition 
        break
    end    
end
```

The error occurs like:

```
??? Size mismatch (size [0 x 0] ~= size [1 x 2]).
The size to the left is the size of the left-hand side of the assignment.
```

How could I fix this bug? how should I modify my Matlab code so that It meets the requirements of C\C++ style for Matlab-coder?

BTW, zero is a reasonable value for coordinate.

Comment: preallocate `I_list`. You know its size beforehand, so fill it with `zeros(size(...,...))`

Comment: If I set I_list = zeros(max_size,max_size),  the calculation of 'I_list = g(I_list)' could be disturbed.Is there other ways to preallocate I_list and coord_list such that the size of  these two variables is variable

Comment: Preallocation is there uniquely to not make the size of the variables variable, and it is exactly what the issue is. Internally, and in C++, this does not exist. Increasing the size of an array means making a copy and deleting the last one. This is inefficient and likely the translation of MATLAB to C++ is not creating code in C++ for it, thus the error. You need to write the MATLAB code with preallocated arrays.

Comment: What line of code and expression is this reported against?

Comment: I used coder.varsize tools and figured it out!